# Changing Auth's Model on the fly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I used `config::set('auth.model','App\Fblogin')` and fetched `config::get('auth.model');` It seems to update the value just fine, but when I try to `Auth::logInUsingId()` it seems like it's still using the default `App\User`. So what do I do so I can use the `App\Fblogin` on my controller?

Comment: It's possible that you are not overriding the config file early enough in the app lifecycle. Different things are executed and requested throughout that app at different times. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/lifecycle for more details. Likely, you will want to override the config no later than in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` boot or register methods. Otherwise, the auth model is likely to be used before being overridden.

Comment: please explain in your question where and how you are setting the auth.model value. The lifecycle of laravel is very specific and requires you to explicitly overrule the behavior at the correct moment.

Comment: yes, like @Luceos said, some code samples would help fixing your problem. I hope you (or somebeody in your dev team) are not _caching_ your configurations.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Laravel 5.1.11 or higher, use this:

```php
auth()->getProvider()->setModel(App\Fblogin::class);
```

---

If you can't/won't upgrade, I'm afraid there's no easy way to achieve this.

The model is resolved through the [`EloquentUserProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php). The model class used is set in the constructor, which cannot be changed at runtime because the property is `protected`.

You can either extend the `EloquentUserProvider`, or you can cheat and set it:

```php
function set_auth_model($model) {
    $closure = (function ($model) { $this->model = $model; });

    $closure = $closure->bindTo(Auth::getProvider());

    $closure($model);
}

set_auth_model(App\Fblogin::class);
```

But really... just upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible but you'd have to try this out. You can set up your own Auth driver, which simply extends the default laravel auth driver but modifies it a bit. You can do this through a provider for instance. In the boot method of the provider you'd say:

```
    $this->app['auth']->extend('my-auth', function ($app) {
        return new Guard(
            new MyUserProvider($app['hash']),
            $app->make('session.store')
        );
    });
```

Note we're no longer passing the model through the constructor. We'll handle that differently.Your MyUserProvider class extends EloquentUserProvider. We override the createModel method to our own version, which instead of using the constructed model name, gets the model name during runtime.

```
class MyUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher)
    { 
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    public function createModel()
    {
        $class = app()->config->get('auth.model');

        return new $class;
    }
}
```

I havent actually tried to see if this works, but you can probably get this to work using this method.